# Why does my file get invalid characters when writing with nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code where I receive data from serialport and append  everything to a text file. The data comes from an Xbee connected to Arduino UNO. I am printing data using Serial.print method. A hash '#' means the end of the message so I print it to a text file. The wireless modules are in AT  (transparent) mode.

I have tried to change the character encoding but it keeps showing the message that my file has invalid characters. Now I convert the data to string but it still does not work.

I am using node.js v0.12.1 and my operating system is Debian testing version.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var sensorData = "";    

var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
  baudrate: 9600
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('Serial port is open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    var c = data.toString('utf8');
    switch(c) {
      case "#":    
        console.log(sensorData);
        fs.appendFile("file.txt", sensorData, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
        sensorData = "";
        break;
      default:
        sensorData += c;
    }        

  });
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Test');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('server is up at: http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This is the message I got:

[image]

I did not get this when executing on Windows platform. What is wrong?

Comment: maybe just throw them away with an additional `case` -- looks like noise on the line, or perhaps some sort of no-op default value -- could be a difference in the win vs linux driver in how no-op is sent down the line?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino strings usually [end with a null byte](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String) (i.e. \00), which probably means your device sends empty strings.

To prevent this, I would detect if your `data` buffer contains a null byte in the first position when it has length 1 and if that's the case, just return so you don't append that content to `sensorData`.

```
serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    if (data.length === 1 && data[0] === 0) return;
    var c = data.toString('utf8');
    ...
```